# Post request for accessing JSON from a website API

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request

I've been collecting some info from a website, and part of that requires me to scrape the max page number on the website to tell my scraper when to stop (there are other ways to do this, but this was the direction I decided in).

Recently they've changed how their max page number is displayed, it is now a variable accessed via a POST request, so when I attempt to scrape it with my old code, it returns the string: `Pagination.PagesCount`.

Now, my problem is I'm having a hard time figuring out how to access this info.

See this code to reproduce my problem:

```
from scrapy import Selector
import requests


url = 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/en-GB/chilled-food/cheese?origin=dropdown&c1=shopgroceries&c2=chilled-food&c3=cheese&clickedon=cheese'


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
           'Referer': 'https://google.com',
           'DNT': '1'}

html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
sel = Selector(text=html)

print(sel)
```

I have accessed data from this site in the past using POST request, for an example the following code will return a dictionary of data on product pricing. But after inspecting the page, fetching the XHR and extensively working my way through a bunch of page requests, I simply can't seem to find where this exact `Pagination.PagesCount` data is being pulled from.

Maybe I've just completely overlooked it, but I would appreciate any help you can give me with this!

```py
import json

headers = {
    "authority": "groceries.aldi.ie",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
    "accept-language": "en-GB",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36",
    "websiteid": "a763fb4a-0224-4ca8-bdaa-a33a4b47a026",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "origin": "https://groceries.aldi.ie",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "referer": "https://groceries.aldi.ie/en-GB/chilled-food/cheese?origin=dropdown&c1=shopgroceries&c2=chilled-food&c3=cheese&clickedon=cheese"
}

body = '{"products":["4088600284026","5391528370382","5391528372836","5391528372850","5391528372874","4088600298696","4088600103709","4088600388700","5035766046028","5000213021934","4088600012551","4088600325934","4088600300153","25389111","4072700001171","4088600012537","4088600012544","4088600013138","4088600013145","4088600103525","4088600103532","4088600103570","4088600103600","4088600135182","4088600141848","4088600142050","4088600158105","4088600217024","4088600217208","4088600241302","4088600249292","4088600249308","4088600280615","4088600281445","4088600283043","4088600284088","4088600295688","4088600295800","4088600295817","4088600303925"]}'

url = 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/api/product/calculatePrices'
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers,data=body)


data = response.text

data = data.replace("'", "\"")
d = json.loads(data)

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the total page number from the API endpoint:

```py
total_pages = round(
        data['ProductSearchResults']['TotalCount'] / data['MaxItemsPerPage']
    )
```

That should give you `3`.

Then, use this to make follow-up requests and get all the product info you need / want.

For example:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.64',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

payload = {
    "CategoryId": "IEL2DB",
    "QueryString": "",
}

search_url = 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/api/aldisearch/search?'
table = []

# Use Session() reuse the connection & persist the data across requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    # Initial request to get the entire product response
    data = s.post(
        search_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(payload)
    ).json()

    # Calculate the total number of pages
    total_pages = round(
        # Total number of products / max number of products per page
        data['ProductSearchResults']['TotalCount'] / data['MaxItemsPerPage']
    )

    # Iterate over each page and extract the product data
    for page in range(1, total_pages + 1):
        payload['QueryString'] = f'&page={page}'
        product_data = (
            s.post(
                search_url,
                headers=headers,
                data=json.dumps(payload),
            ).json()['ProductSearchResults']['SearchResults']
        )
        # Extend the table with the product data
        table.extend(
            [
                product['DisplayName'],
                product['DisplayPrice'],
                product['ProductId'],
                f"https://groceries.aldi.ie/product{product['Url']}",
            ] for product in product_data
        )

# Create a DataFrame from the table list
df = pd.DataFrame(
    table,
    columns=['Name', 'Price', 'ID', 'URL'],
    # Set the index to start from 1
    index=range(1, len(table) + 1),
)
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

You should get a table with `104` items that looks like this:

```html
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     | Name                                                    | Price   |            ID | URL                                                                                                                                    |
|-----+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1 | Grated Mozzarella 250g Emporium                         | £1.59   | 4088500723212 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-mozzarella-250g-emporium/4088500723212                                                |
|   2 | Mild White Cheddar Sticks 6x20g Emporium                | £1.79   | 4088600528465 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mild-white-cheddar-sticks-6x20g-emporium/4088600528465                                       |
|   3 | Mature White Cheddar Sticks 6x20g Emporium              | £1.79   | 4088600528458 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mature-white-cheddar-sticks-6x20g-emporium/4088600528458                                     |
|   4 | Breaded Mozzarella Sticks 240g 12 Pack Emporium         | £2.49   | 4088600544403 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-breaded-mozzarella-sticks-240g-12-pack-emporium/4088600544403                                |
|   5 | Cooleeney Farm Handmade Irish Cheese Tipperary Brie 80g | £1.79   | 4088600499635 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-cooleeney-farm-handmade-irish-cheese-tipperary-brie-80g-specially-selected/4088600499635     |
|   6 | Coconut Oil Alternative To Cheddar Block 200g Plant Men | £2.79   | 4088600551012 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-coconut-oil-alternative-to-cheddar-block-200g-plant-menu/4088600551012                       |
|   7 | Coconut Oil Alternative To Cheddar Slices 180g 9 Pack P | £2.79   | 4088600551029 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-coconut-oil-alternative-to-cheddar-slices-180g-9-pack-plant-menu/4088600551029               |
|   8 | Cheestrings (160g) 8 X 20g Strings & Things             | £3.49   | 5000187130946 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-cheestrings-160g-8-x-20g-strings-things/5000187130946                                        |
|   9 | Parmigiano Reggiano 200g Specially Selected             | £3.69   | 4088600455792 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-parmigiano-reggiano-200g-specially-selected/4088600455792                                    |
|  10 | Grana Padano 200g Emporium                              | £2.69   | 4061462209802 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grana-padano-200g-emporium/4061462209802                                                     |
|  11 | Vintage Red Fox Red Leicester & Sweet Chilli Cheese Bak | £3.99   | 4088600539737 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-vintage-red-fox-red-leicester-sweet-chilli-cheese-bake-150g-specially-selected/4088600539737 |
|  12 | Spreadable Lighter 110g Seriously                       | £1.69   | 3228023190059 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-spreadable-lighter-110g-seriously/3228023190059                                              |
|  13 | Spreadable Original 110g Seriously                      | £1.69   | 3228023190042 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-spreadable-original-110g-seriously/3228023190042                                             |
|  14 | Monterey Jack & BBQ Burger Melt 100g Emporium           | £2.49   | 4088600558912 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-monterey-jack-bbq-burger-melt-100g-emporium/4088600558912                                    |
|  15 | Cheddar & Caramelised Red Onion Chutney Burger Melt 100 | £2.49   | 4088600558943 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-cheddar-caramelised-red-onion-chutney-burger-melt-100g-emporium/4088600558943                |
|  16 | Breaded Cypriot Grilling Cheese Fries 170g 10 Pack Empo | £2.49   | 4088600562438 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-breaded-cypriot-grilling-cheese-fries-170g-10-pack-emporium/4088600562438                    |
|  17 | 8 Cheese Triangles 140g Emporium                        | £0.99   | 4088600282527 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-8-cheese-triangles-140g-emporium/4088600282527                                               |
|  18 | 8 Lighter Cheese Triangles 140g Emporium                | £0.99   | 4088600282534 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-8-lighter-cheese-triangles-140g-emporium/4088600282534                                       |
|  19 | 15 Cheesy Singles 225g Everyday Essentials              | £0.89   | 4088600086392 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-15-cheesy-singles-225g-everyday-essentials/4088600086392                                     |
|  20 | Greek Feta Cheese 200g Emporium                         | £1.29   | 4088600342733 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-greek-feta-cheese-200g-emporium/4088600342733                                                |
|  21 | Scottish Fat Free Cottage Cheese 300g Glen Lochy        | £0.99   | 4088600140025 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-scottish-fat-free-cottage-cheese-300g-glen-lochy/4088600140025                               |
|  22 | Scottish Fat Free Pineapple Cottage Cheese 300g Glen Lo | £0.99   | 4088600140032 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-scottish-fat-free-pineapple-cottage-cheese-300g-glen-lochy/4088600140032                     |
|  23 | Scottish Fat Free Onion & Chive Cottage Cheese 300g Gle | £0.99   | 4088600140049 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-scottish-fat-free-onion-chive-cottage-cheese-300g-glen-lochy/4088600140049                   |
|  24 | Scottish Natural Cottage Cheese 300g Glen Lochy         | £0.99   | 4088600243641 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-scottish-natural-cottage-cheese-300g-glen-lochy/4088600243641                                |
|  25 | Black Pepper Irish Cheddar Slices 140g 5 Pack Ardagh    | £1.49   | 4088600223094 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-black-pepper-irish-cheddar-slices-140g-5-pack-ardagh/4088600223094                           |
|  26 | Smoky Irish Cheddar Slices 140g 5 Pack Ardagh           | £1.49   | 4088600223100 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-smoky-irish-cheddar-slices-140g-5-pack-ardagh/4088600223100                                  |
|  27 | Cheesy Singles 400g Emporium                            | £1.29   | 4088600236803 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-cheesy-singles-400g-emporium/4088600236803                                                   |
|  28 | Light Cheesy Singles 200g Emporium                      | £0.59   | 4088600236810 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-light-cheesy-singles-200g-emporium/4088600236810                                             |
|  29 | Hard Goats Cheese 130g Emporium                         | £2.09   | 4088600253329 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-hard-goats-cheese-130g-emporium/4088600253329                                                |
|  30 | Mozzarella 200g Everyday Essentials                     | £0.59   | 4088600286808 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mozzarella-200g-everyday-essentials/4088600286808                                            |
|  31 | Light Mozzarella 200g Everyday Essentials               | £0.59   | 4088600286815 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-light-mozzarella-200g-everyday-essentials/4088600286815                                      |
|  32 | Irish Lighter Mild Red Cheese Slices 200g 10 Pack Ardag | £1.59   | 4088600001562 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-lighter-mild-red-cheese-slices-200g-10-pack-ardagh/4088600001562                       |
|  33 | 10 Slices Irish Mature Red Cheddar 200g Ardagh          | £1.69   | 4088600001579 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-10-slices-irish-mature-red-cheddar-200g-ardagh/4088600001579                                 |
|  34 | Irish Mature White Cheddar Slices 200g Ardagh           | £1.49   | 4088600001586 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-mature-white-cheddar-slices-200g-ardagh/4088600001586                                  |
|  35 | Grated Red Cheddar And Mozzarella 250g Ardagh           | £1.99   | 4088600001593 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-red-cheddar-and-mozzarella-250g-ardagh/4088600001593                                  |
|  36 | 10 Slices Irish Medium Red Cheddar 200g Ardagh          | £1.69   | 4088600001609 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-10-slices-irish-medium-red-cheddar-200g-ardagh/4088600001609                                 |
|  37 | Grated Irish Mature White Cheddar 250g Ardagh           | £1.99   | 4088600001616 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-irish-mature-white-cheddar-250g-ardagh/4088600001616                                  |
|  38 | Irish Medium Red Cheddar 200g Ardagh                    | £1.69   | 4088600001630 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-medium-red-cheddar-200g-ardagh/4088600001630                                           |
|  39 | Irish Mature Red Cheddar 200g Ardagh                    | £1.69   | 4088600001654 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-mature-red-cheddar-200g-ardagh/4088600001654                                           |
|  40 | Lighter Grated Irish Mild Red Cheese 200g Ardagh        | £2.29   | 4088600001692 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-lighter-grated-irish-mild-red-cheese-200g-ardagh/4088600001692                               |
|  41 | Irish Mature White Cheddar 355g Ardagh                  | £2.19   | 4088600018799 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-mature-white-cheddar-355g-ardagh/4088600018799                                         |
|  42 | Mini Roulé With Tomato & Basil 100g Emporium            | £1.99   | 4088600036007 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mini-roule-with-tomato-basil-100g-emporium/4088600036007                                     |
|  43 | Irish Lighter Mature White Cheese Slices 200g 10 Pack A | £1.59   | 4088600044316 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-lighter-mature-white-cheese-slices-200g-10-pack-ardagh/4088600044316                   |
|  44 | Irish Mild Red Cheddar Slices 200g 10 Pack Ardagh       | £1.65   | 4088600044460 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-mild-red-cheddar-slices-200g-10-pack-ardagh/4088600044460                              |
|  45 | 10 Slices Irish Mild White Cheddar 200g Ardagh          | £1.65   | 4088600044477 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-10-slices-irish-mild-white-cheddar-200g-ardagh/4088600044477                                 |
|  46 | Full Fat Soft Cheese 200g Emporium                      | £0.89   | 4088600046648 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-full-fat-soft-cheese-200g-emporium/4088600046648                                             |
|  47 | Reduced Fat Soft Cheese 200g Emporium                   | £0.89   | 4088600046662 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-reduced-fat-soft-cheese-200g-emporium/4088600046662                                          |
|  48 | Reduced Fat Soft Cheese 200g Emporium                   | £0.89   | 4088600046679 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-reduced-fat-soft-cheese-200g-emporium/4088600046679                                          |
|  49 | Dip-it Cheese Dip With Breadsticks 3x50g 150g Emporium  | £1.79   | 4088600047096 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-dipit-cheese-dipwith-breadsticks-3x50g-150g-emporium/4088600047096                           |
|  50 | Dip-it Cheese Dip With Crackers 3x45g 135g Emporium     | £1.79   | 4088600047102 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-dipit-cheese-dipwith-crackers-3x45g-135g-emporium/4088600047102                              |
|  51 | Mascarpone 250g Emporium                                | £1.29   | 4088600047119 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mascarpone-250g-emporium/4088600047119                                                       |
|  52 | Ricotta 250g Emporium                                   | £1.29   | 4088600047126 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-ricotta-250g-emporium/4088600047126                                                          |
|  53 | Mini Roulé With Garlic And Herb 100g Emporium           | £1.99   | 4088600047324 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mini-roule-with-garlic-and-herb-100g-emporium/4088600047324                                  |
|  54 | Mini Roule With Pineapple & Almond 100g Emporium        | £1.99   | 4088600047331 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mini-roule-with-pineapple-almond-100g-emporium/4088600047331                                 |
|  55 | Mini Roulé With Black Pepper And Paprika 100g Emporium  | £1.99   | 4088600047348 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mini-roule-with-black-pepper-and-paprika-100g-emporium/4088600047348                         |
|  56 | Wensleydale With Cranberry 200g Emporium                | £1.89   | 4088600048154 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-wensleydale-with-cranberry-200g-emporium/4088600048154                                       |
|  57 | Wensleydale With Apricot 200g Emporium                  | £1.89   | 4088600048161 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-wensleydale-with-apricot-200g-emporium/4088600048161                                         |
|  58 | Double Gloucester With Onion & Chives 200g Emporium     | £1.89   | 4088600048178 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-double-gloucester-with-onion-chives-200g-emporium/4088600048178                              |
|  59 | Spicy Cheddar With Chilli 200g Emporium                 | £1.89   | 4088600048185 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-spicy-cheddar-with-chilli-200g-emporium/4088600048185                                        |
|  60 | Smoked Cheddar Cheese 200g Emporium                     | £1.89   | 4088600048192 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-smoked-cheddar-cheese-200g-emporium/4088600048192                                            |
|  61 | Dutch Cheese Emmental Slices 16 Pack Emporium           | £2.49   | 4088600048253 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-dutch-cheese-emmental-slices-16-pack-emporium/4088600048253                                  |
|  62 | 16 Dutch Cheese Maasdam Slices 400g Emporium            | £2.49   | 4088600048260 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-16-dutch-cheese-maasdam-slices-400g-emporium/4088600048260                                   |
|  63 | 16 Dutch Edam Cheese Slices 400g Emporium               | £2.79   | 4088600048277 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-16-dutch-edam-cheese-slices-400g-emporium/4088600048277                                      |
|  64 | 16 Dutch Gouda Cheese Slices 400g Emporium              | £2.79   | 4088600048284 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-16-dutch-gouda-cheese-slices-400g-emporium/4088600048284                                     |
|  65 | French Goat's Cheese Plain 150g Emporium                | £2.09   | 4088600048345 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-french-goats-cheese-plain-150g-emporium/4088600048345                                        |
|  66 | French Goats' Cheese Garlic & Herb 150g Emporium        | £2.09   | 4088600048352 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-french-goats-cheese-garlic-herb-150g-emporium/4088600048352                                  |
|  67 | French Goats' Cheese 180g Emporium                      | £2.09   | 4088600048369 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-french-goats-cheese-180g-emporium/4088600048369                                              |
|  68 | Italian Mozzarella 240g ( Drained) Emporium             | £0.75   | 4088600058641 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-italian-mozzarella-240g-drained-emporium/4088600058641                                       |
|  69 | Made For Sharing Mature Cheddar Cheese Bake 150g Specia | £3.99   | 4088600063713 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-made-for-sharing-mature-cheddar-cheese-bake-150g-specially-selected/4088600063713            |
|  70 | Grated Grana Padano 100g Emporium                       | £1.25   | 4088600064017 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-grana-padano-100g-emporium/4088600064017                                              |
|  71 | Shaved Parmigiano Reggiano 80g Emporium                 | £1.25   | 4088600064024 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-shaved-parmigiano-reggiano-80g-emporium/4088600064024                                        |
|  72 | Grated Irish Mature Red Cheddar 250g Ardagh             | £1.99   | 4088600001623 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-irish-mature-red-cheddar-250g-ardagh/4088600001623                                    |
|  73 | Spicy Irish Cheddar Slices 140g 5 Pack Ardagh           | £1.49   | 4088600223087 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-spicy-irish-cheddar-slices-140g-5-pack-ardagh/4088600223087                                  |
|  74 | Grated 50% Less Fat Irish Mature White Cheese 200g Arda | £2.29   | 4088600106847 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-50-less-fat-irish-mature-white-cheese-200g-ardagh/4088600106847                       |
|  75 | Lighter Grated Mild Red & Mozzarella Cheese 200g Ardagh | £2.49   | 4088600037936 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-lighter-grated-mild-red-mozzarella-cheese-200g-ardagh/4088600037936                          |
|  76 | German Smoked Cheese With Ham Slices 200g Emporium      | £2.19   | 4088600046594 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-german-smoked-cheese-with-ham-slices-200g-emporium/4088600046594                             |
|  77 | German Smoked Cheese Plain Slices 200g Emporium         | £2.19   | 4088600046570 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-german-smoked-cheese-plain-slices-200g-emporium/4088600046570                                |
|  78 | 10 German Smoked Cheese With Jalapeño Slices 200g Empor | £2.19   | 4088600046556 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-10-german-smoked-cheese-with-jalapeno-slices-200g-emporium/4088600046556                     |
|  79 | 24 Months Matured Irish Vintage White Cheddar 250g Spec | £2.49   | 4088600017396 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-24-months-matured-irish-vintage-white-cheddar-250g-specially-selected/4088600017396          |
|  80 | Irish Hand Cut Vintage White Cheddar 160g Specially Sel | £2.19   | 4088600044323 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-hand-cut-vintage-white-cheddar-160g-specially-selected/4088600044323                   |
|  81 | 18 Months Matured Irish Hand Cut Vintage Red Cheddar 16 | £2.19   | 4088600007298 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-18-months-matured-irish-hand-cut-vintage-red-cheddar-160g-specially-selected/4088600007298   |
|  82 | Irish Extra Mature White Cheddar 350g Ardagh            | £2.59   | 4088600035086 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-extra-mature-white-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600035086                                   |
|  83 | Irish Extra Mature Red Cheddar 350g Ardagh              | £2.59   | 4088600035079 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-extra-mature-red-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600035079                                     |
|  84 | Irish Mild Red Cheddar 350g Ardagh                      | £1.99   | 4088600018386 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-mild-red-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600018386                                             |
|  85 | Irish Mild White Cheddar 350g Ardagh                    | £1.99   | 4088600018362 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-mild-white-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600018362                                           |
|  86 | Irish Medium Red Cheddar 350g Ardagh                    | £2.19   | 4088600018416 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-medium-red-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600018416                                           |
|  87 | Irish Medium White Cheddar 350g Ardagh                  | £2.19   | 4088600018379 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-medium-white-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600018379                                         |
|  88 | Irish Mature Red Cheddar 350g Ardagh                    | £2.19   | 4088600018294 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-mature-red-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600018294                                           |
|  89 | West Cork Irish Buffalo Milk Mozzarella 290g (125g Drai | £2.59   | 4088600075068 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-west-cork-irish-buffalo-milk-mozzarella-290g-125g-drained-specially-selected/4088600075068   |
|  90 | Irish Vintage White Cheddar 350g Ardagh                 | £3.29   | 4088600001647 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-irish-vintage-white-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600001647                                        |
|  91 | Halloumi 225g Emporium                                  | £2.25   | 4088600155814 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-halloumi-225g-emporium/4088600155814                                                         |
|  92 | French Baking Camembert 250g Specially Selected         | £2.99   | 4088600231242 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-french-baking-camembert-250g-specially-selected/4088600231242                                |
|  93 | French Brie De Meaux 165g Specially Selected            | £2.99   | 4088600265360 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-french-brie-de-meaux-165g-specially-selected/4088600265360                                   |
|  94 | French Roquefort 125g Specially Selected                | £2.99   | 4088600265353 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-french-roquefort-125g-specially-selected/4088600265353                                       |
|  95 | 17 Slices Irish Medium Red Cheddar 350g Ardagh          | £2.59   | 4088600000398 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-17-slices-irish-medium-red-cheddar-350g-ardagh/4088600000398                                 |
|  96 | West Cork Irish Buffalo Mozzarella Pearls 290g Speciall | £2.69   | 4088600154824 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-west-cork-irish-buffalo-mozzarella-pearls-290g-specially-selected/4088600154824              |
|  97 | Grated Irish Mild Red Cheddar 475g Ardagh               | £2.69   | 4088600018287 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-irish-mild-red-cheddar-475g-ardagh/4088600018287                                      |
|  98 | Grated Red Cheddar And Mozzarella 475g Ardagh           | £3.49   | 4088600033297 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-grated-red-cheddar-and-mozzarella-475g-ardagh/4088600033297                                  |
|  99 | Dutch Extra Mature Gouda 180g Specially Selected        | £2.99   | 4088600040776 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-dutch-extra-mature-gouda-180g-specially-selected/4088600040776                               |
| 100 | 12 Month Matured Comté 180g Specially Selected          | £2.99   | 4088600346106 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-12-month-matured-comte-180g-specially-selected/4088600346106                                 |
| 101 | Rich & Creamy Cashel Blue 150g Specially Selected       | £3.29   | 4088600459462 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-rich-creamy-cashel-blue-150g-specially-selected/4088600459462                                |
| 102 | Spanish Manchego 175g Specially Selected                | £2.99   | 4088600040769 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-spanish-manchego-175g-specially-selected/4088600040769                                       |
| 103 | Swiss Le Gruyère Aop Reserve 150g Specially Selected    | £2.99   | 4088600346113 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-swiss-le-gruyere-aopreserve-150g-specially-selected/4088600346113                            |
| 104 | Mini Original Cheese (200g) 10 X 20g Babybel            | £3.29   | 3073780918763 | https://groceries.aldi.ie/product/en-GB/p-mini-original-cheese-200g-10-x-20g-babybel/3073780918763                                     |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer, you've gone above and beyond.

Comment: One quick question, where is it receiving directions to scrape the page in question, is that info contained in the payload? And if so, where did you pull that payload info from?

Comment: It's in the payload under `CategoryId`. I got this from the XHR tab in the Dev Tools.

Comment: Ok cool, I get you. Could you tell me which POST/GET request this contained in? Sorry for all the questions, I just can't seem to find it myself, I'm relatively knew to this kind of stuff.

Comment: It's from a POST request to this endpoint - https://groceries.aldi.ie/api/aldisearch/search. If you go to cheese page and then click, say, page 2, you'll see in XHR the above endpoint. In the payload is the category id.